# Problema con jquery en un select

Tags: javascript, mvc, php7

Estoy usando el modelo `MVC` con `PHP v7.`, `HTML5` y `SQL server 2008`, tengo una pagina donde despliego un cierto listado y por cada registro tengo un botón para actualizar.
 Al oprimir el botón llama a una función en `JS`, que a través de `AJAX`, trae la información a actualizar en un formulario. En el formulario tengo un `SELECT` donde quiero que al cargar la información, este muestre la opción con la que se guardo con anterioridad.
 He realizado la carga con varias opciones, pero solo si abro el `SELECT` aparece la opción seleccionada pero no se muestra en en el `SELECT`, solo se muestra si lo despliego.

He usado el siguiente código `Jquery`:

```
$("#field option[value="+info+"]").attr("selected", "selected");

$("#field option[value="+info+"]").attr("selected", true);

$("#field").val(info.trim()).attr('selected', "selected");

$('select[name="field"]').find('option[value='+info+']').attr("selected", true);

document.querySelector('#field-8 [value="' + info + '"]').selected = true;
```

Todos si seleccionan el valor que deben pero en el texto no se muestra.

Ejemplo de que si selecciona la opcion que debe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al cargar la informacion que se debe de actualizar aparace:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con algunas librerías, como [select2](https://select2.github.io/) por ejemplo, tienes que hacer `trigger` del evento `change` para que te muestre el resultado.

Prueba de esa manera:

```
$("#field").trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente tienes que hacer uso de la función `.trigger(<evento>)`, te dejo un breve ejemplo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('select').val("2");
    $('select').trigger('change');
  }, 2000)
});
```

```css
select{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="0">-- Seleccionar --</option>
  <option selected="" value="1">Opción 1 (seleccionada por defecto)</option>
  <option value="2">Opción 2 (seleccionada por jQuery)</option>
  <option value="3">Opción 3</option>
</select>
```